# Mostrar miniatura de imagem ou do vídeo de site assim que digitar url do site

Tags: php, javascript, html

Eu tenho um sistema de postagem, mas se eu colocar por exemplo: "https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask" o sistema vai interpretar dessa forma e vai imprimir assim. Gostaria de saber como faço para antes do usuário postar, aparecer uma prévia da imagem ou vídeo e depois que postar, aparecer como uma imagem externa ou vídeo externo. Assim como no Facebook.

Comment: Eu acredito que seja 'simples' mas nem tanto assim, mas não sei afirmar, por isso vou só comentar, acho que seja uma requisição via websocket e faz a leitura do link, e pela leitura estrutura das páginas html, as tags 'article', ou pelo tamanho da 'h4' (há mais coisas que podem ser lidas) e devolve uma resposta formatada, ou pode ser até que exista uma api do google pra isso, mas não consegui encontrar.

Comment: Vlw amigo, estou quase terminando meu projeto. Toda a ajuda é bem vinda.

Comment: @Luizinho eu também acredito que seja fácil, aqui vai ser meio difícil conseguir um código completo, aconselho pesquisar na internet assuntos parecidos e ir alterado para seu código.

Comment: Vlw pelo conselho. :)